# python - use argparse but have option for raw_input

Tags: python

I have some code like so -

```
## ARGUMENTS
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("environment", help="Environment to change queue")
parser.add_argument("queue", help="Queue to change")
parser.add_argument("limit", help="Limit value")
args = parser.parse_args()

current_user = getpass.getuser()
environment = raw_input("Environment you are in: ")
queue = raw_input("Queue you wish to modify: ")
limit = raw_input("Limit value of Queue: ")
```

What I want to do is have it so that if the arguments aren't provided when calling the file -

```
prog.py DEV test_queue 1
```

I want it to ask the inputs to get the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're willing to use named arguments...

```
## ARGUMENTS
import argparse
import getpass

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--environment", help="Environment to change queue",
                    default=None)
parser.add_argument("--queue", help="Queue to change", default=None)
parser.add_argument("--limit", help="Limit value", default=None)
args = parser.parse_args()

current_user = getpass.getuser()

environment = args.environment if args.environment else raw_input("Environment you are in: ")
queue = args.queue if args.queue else raw_input("Queue you wish to modify: ")
limit = args.limit if args.limit else raw_input("Limit value of Queue: ")


print environment, queue, limit
```

Comment: Much more elegant than I figured out thank you!  I'm guessing there's no way around the whole having to do --environment xxx --queue xxx --limit x ?

Comment: got me to the answer I got rid of the named arguments by doing the following - 

`parser.add_argument('environment', nargs='?', default=None)`
`parser.add_argument('queue', nargs='?', default=None)`
`parser.add_argument('limit', nargs='?', default=None)`

Comment: Possibly (for e.g.) `args.environment if args.environment is not None....` would be preferable since it may be valid to provide empty strings as argument values.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want positional arguments I suggest to skip argparse and go with old school sys.argv:

```
import sys
import getpass

current_user = getpass.getuser()
argv = sys.argv[1:]
environment = argv[0] if len(argv) > 0 else raw_input("Environment you are in: ")
queue = argv[1] if len(argv) > 1 else raw_input("Queue you wish to modify: ")
limit = argv[2] if len(argv) > 2 else raw_input("Limit value: ")
```